# Infinite linear order with endpoints which is non-dense

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

In the process of answering questions about normal models, I had to prove the following:
Any normal model of $\chi$ is a non-dense linear order with a least and greatest element. The next question then asks to show that $\chi$ has an infinite normal model using the compactness theorem. My question is: Could anyone give me an example of an infinite non-dense linear order with a least and greatest element? I don't see how it's possible...

Comment: I have to admit that I don't recall meeting the term "normal model" before.

Comment: It's probably just something used as a place holder, I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter in terms of the question. It just stumped me because I didn't see how you could make it infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb Z\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

Or consider $\Bbb N+\Bbb N^*$, that is, put all the non-negative integers on the bottom, then the negative integers on the top, but don't reverse the order of the negative integers, so you get something like this: 
$$0,1,2,3,\ldots,n,\ldots,-n,\ldots,-3,-2,-1$$

Comment: Aha! I didn't know that was allowed. Thank you. :D I understand the first example, but it feels a bit... cheap if that makes sense. I love the second example! That's helped solidify the concept in my mind, so thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, if you just want to contradict density you can just ensure it fails at one point. So for example consider $[0,1]\cup\{2\}\cup[3,4]$ It's not dense because $2$ has immediate successor and predecessor; but it has endpoints.

Comment: That's also a nice idea. The problem I was having in trying to imagine it is that, if it has endpoints, then the infinity must be contained in the middle and I didn't see how it wasn't dense. If it wasn't dense, I didn't get how the infinity could be included in a bound. So, I think the answer you've given that helps the most is the second one with the natural numbers as that solves both problems for me at once.

Comment: Yes, I figured that you're looking for something which is not dense at all; not just at one or two points.